# Definition of subarray

Tags: arrays

I am unclear about the definition of a sub array. Does it mean a contiguous list of indexes , such as a[i..j] or can it be non contiguous, such as a[0], a[5],a[6]

Comment: @PIZZICATO: how does it matter

Comment: to show you some example code :)  Dante answer got it solved though...

Comment: @Programmer It **does** matter because structures can be named differently in different programming languages. You can still [edit] your question to make it better. And Dante's answer no longer exists.

Answer (score 16):

Subarrays are arrays within another array.Subarrays contains contiguous elements whereas subsequences are not.

An Example would make it clear

Consider an array {1,2,3,4}

List of all its **subarrays** are 
 `{},{1},{2},{3},{4},{1,2},{2,3},{3,4},{1,2,3,4}`

List of all its **subsequences** are `{},{1},{2},{3},{4},{1,2},{1,3},{1,4},{2,3},{2,4},{3,4},{1,2,3},{1,2,4},{1,3,4},{2,3,4},{1,2,3,4}`

Comment: you have missed the subarrays {1,2,3} and {2,3,4} in list of all subarrays.

Answer (score 9):

I think the subarray means the array in which the contiguousness is based on the index . for example lets take an example

2 3 1 3 1 (index are 0,1,2,3,4 respectively )

so subarray is  2,3,1 3 (index 0,1,2,3) 
But (1,2 1) (index 2,0,4) cannot be a subarray coz the indexes are non-contiguous ..

Hope its helpfull ;)

Answer (score 3):

In most contexts it refers to a contiguous index subset.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_subarray_problem

Answer (score 3):

Subarray refers to contiguous list whereas Subsequence refers to non-contiguous list.

Answer (score 1):

Well, SubArray is contiguous and SubSequence is not. if you want to complete the note click on the link mentioned at the end. if you are too lazy to click then read here:

Here is the Definition of Subarray and SubSequeences:
A sub-array is a contiguous part of the array. An array that is inside another array. For example, consider the array [1, 2, 3, 4], There are 10 non-empty sub-arrays. The subarrays are (1), (2), (3), (4), (1,2), (2,3), (3,4), (1,2,3), (2,3,4), and (1,2,3,4). Generally, for an array/string of size n, there are n*(n+1)/2 non-empty subarrays/substrings.

A subsequence is a sequence that can be derived from another series by zero or more elements, without changing the order of the remaining elements.
For the same example, there are 15 sub-sequences. They are (1), (2), (3), (4), (1,2), (1,3),(1,4), (2,3), (2,4), (3,4), (1,2,3), (1,2,4), (1,3,4), (2,3,4), (1,2,3,4). More generally, we can say that for a sequence of size n, we can have (2^n-1) non-empty sub-sequences in total. and including empty subsequence 2^n subsequences in total

Definition / Credit : [Click Here to Read full note / SubArry And SubSequence](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/subarraysubstring-vs-subsequence-and-programs-to-generate-them/)

Answer (score 0):

A subarray is a contiguous (consecutive) portion of an array. It is a subset of elements taken from the original array, maintaining their relative order. In simpler terms, a subarray is formed by selecting a range of elements from an array, without skipping any elements

Let us write all the subarrays for the array: [3, 5, 1, 2, 7, 4]

The sub-arrays for this array are:

please click the below image description you can find possible subarrays for above array
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hXqpu.png)

Total number of subarrays possible in an array of length N = ( N*(N+1))/2

Note:

1. individual elements of the array are also considered subarrays.
2. empty array not a subarray.