# Can an element in an array itself be called a subarray?

Tags: c++, arrays

For example:
int arr[5]={1,2,3,4,5};
Now here can I say that each element is a subarray of arr? I got confused when the question asked to find count subarrays with a given target sum.

Comment: You can get familiar with this topic in its general sense [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subsequence).

Comment: @rawrex I do not think that the link you provided explains the meaning of "subarray" as meant by the author of the assignment. It is not even the same word and what the author/teacher actually means is best asked from them.

Comment: prem gupta. If the assignment does not provide a few examples (which most assignments of this kind do), there is no way to know for sure, except asking the teacher/author.

Comment: In my opinion a subarray would be things like [1], [1,2], [1,2,3], etc.

Comment: @Yunnosch The reasoning behind my comment is that *in general* it would be beneficial to firstly look at an array as a case of a sequence. Thus, an element can (and should) be considered as a subarray.

Comment: How can we be sure that a subarray is not simply an array that is submersible?

Comment: IMO if it works for `2` contiguous members of the array, it works for a single element. I think even the `C++` Standard considers single objects as arrays of `1` in certain respects when dealing with pointers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each element of an array can itself be considered a sub-array of size 1. So, given:

```
int arr[5]={1,2,3,4,5};
```

each of 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 are subarrays:

```
{1}, {2}, {3}, {4}, {5}
```

In the question you were given, this is important in that if an element on its own matches the target sum, it counst as a sub-array towards your solution

Also, this seems to have been answered here: [Definition of subarray](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5298300/definition-of-subarray/45686639)

Answer (score 0):

> A subarray is a contiguous part of array. An array that is inside
> another array.

So every element inside an array is subarray itself as it does not contradict the above definition. So in such questions as long as it mentions subarray you should interpret it according to above definition.

Ex subarray of `{1,2,3}` are `{1}`,  `{2}` , `{3}` , `{1,2}` , `{2,3}` , `{1,2,3}` .

Answer (score -1):

```
You can show all subarray by using bit-mask arrays.
    for(int i=1;i<pow(2,6);i++){
        int cur_sum = 0;
        int v[5],cnt=0;
        for(int j=0;j<5;j++){
            if(i&(pow(j,2))==1){
                cur_sum+=(j+1);
                v[cnt++]=j+1;
            }
        }
        if(sum==cur_sum){
            for(int j=0;j<cnt;j++)cout<<v[j]<<' ';
            return ;
        }
    }
```

Comment: This does not answer the original question. The code does *something*, but there's no explanation as to what it is. Besides, `v` is uninitialized, `pow` need not return an integer, `sum` has not been defined. I'm afraid this answer is useless, mostly because of no explanation accompanying it.